# JS Node returning only numbers and not proper values

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to use js node to display a mysql query results so I can later output it to a webpage.

At the moment, I'm just outputting the resulsts of a query into the console, the code is below:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const querystring = require('querystring')

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host    : 'localhost',
    user    : 'webuser',
    password: 'p0ssw0rd',
    database: 'balancesheet2'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected!');
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM balancesheet2.orders', function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result = querystring.stringify(result,' | ',' :=');
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
    });

});
```

The results i'm getting are just as below:

```
Result: 0 := | 1 := | 2 := | 3 :=
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies, is it with the code, or is it with the database somewhere?

Comment: Calling `querystring.stringify` on the results array seems a fairly odd thing to do. What result are you expecting from it?

Comment: Just do `console.log(result)`, and leave out the `querystring.stringify`..   Node.js console.log isn't the best at displaying object properties and even worse if you prepend it with a  string, for better output you might also consider util.inspect, -> https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: @Keith I'm not sure how or why it worked, but last time I tried that it just gave [object, object], I'm not sure if it was an access permission I changed or what.

Comment: If you just do -> `console.log(result)`, it will work ok,.. But if you do `console.log("something:" + result)` it will not work ok..  That's because Object.toString() returns `[object Object]`.

Comment: @Keith +1 It was that simple Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is a array so you probably need to loop over to the content of `result` to get the values printed otherwise the existing code is simply printing the index of the array. Also note that the `querystring.stringify()` method produces a URL query string from a given obj by iterating through the object's "own properties".

Comment: It's an odd thing to do, but `querystring.stringify` will loop through the `result`, which is why the OP is getting the numbers (`0`, `1`, etc.) which are the own properties of the array. So the question is why the values are all blank.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, it does that to make this happen OP needs to loop over `result` and do `querystring.stringify()` for each of that object.

Comment: Well, *maybe*. It depends on what he/she actually wants to achieve.

Comment: When I first ran the script without stringify, the results were all [object, object]. So I looked into solutions to that and found querystring.stringify().
I'm not sure what loop I would use or how I'd go about it

Comment: @PeterCollins what do you want to achieve? What's your expected output?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I'm expecting that the query results to be output to a table. I thought it would be like a normal SQL query, but apparently not.